# Trouble unwrapping JSON Array to a String Value

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I have been struggling with JSON for a few days.  I am trying to create a POST request to my web server for a username, that will return information on said user.  I have managed to get the JSON response two ways, but I cannot cast any of the elements of the Array to a string.  I am using the SWIFTYJSON API too.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var token = "barrymanilow"
    var endPoint = "http://www.never.money/simple_app7.php"


@IBOutlet weak var firstLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    submitAction(self)
}

func submitAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.mindyour.money/simple_app7.php");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

    // Compose a query string
    let postString = "token=\(token)";

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil{
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        // Print out response body
        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("responseString = \(responseString)")

        //Let's convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:

        var err: NSError?
        var myJSON = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error:&err) as? NSArray

var json : JSON = JSON(data: data)

        let results: AnyObject? = myJSON?.valueForKey("player_username")
        println("\(results)")
let result2 = json["player_username"].string


    }

    task.resume()
}
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working, can anybody help me?

Comment: I only know objective-c, but as a general rule you're better off working with AFNetworking or another framework instead of trying to roll your own. Going it alone gets more and more complicated as your app gets more linked up to backend api's.

Comment: your question is unclear. What does not work, the SwiftyJSON object or the NSJSONSerialization? whats the returned JSON schema?

Comment: Can you show the json that is being returned?

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, the commentary below helped me solve it.  I'll be sure to make my next question clearer though.  I'm also gonna do some reading on AFNetworking too.  Any tips on what to read would be most appreciated.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that when using `NSJSONSerialization` you're casting your JSON response as an NSArray, so for example to get the first item's `player_username` with SwiftyJSON you would do:

```
let result2 = json[0]["player_username"].string
```

It should work without casting `json[0]` to a dictionary first because thanks to SwiftyJSON the compiler knows that `json[0]` is a dictionary.

If for some reason `json[0]` is not automatically subscriptable, you can do:

```
let playerOneDic = json[0].dictionary
let result2 = playerOneDic["player_username"].string
```

---

Otherwise, without SwiftyJSON, you would have to do something like this:

```
if let playerOne = myJSON?[0] as? [String:AnyObject] {
    if let username = playerOne["player_username"] as? String {
        println(username)
    }
}
```